# Convert MainActivity with actionbar/toolbar and floatingaction button to Anko

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, anko

I am trying to learn how to use Kotlin/Anko.

I have gone thru the examples [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) and also cloned the template project and can understand how to do some basic stuff, but as an exercise I wanted to convert this simple activity (generated from a blank activity in Android Studio and converted to Kotlin) to use Anko as well.  There are not a lot of examples around for Anko, most are just copies of what is on the above referenced github page.

Can someone demonstrate how to go about and convert the following into Anko DSL?

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolBar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar)
        val fab = findViewById(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton
        fab.setOnClickListener { view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace this with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show() }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            println("settings clicked on ")
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gmail.npnster.mykotlinfirstproject.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.gmail.npnster.mykotlinfirstproject.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ankoView` method to create `View`s without DSL methods inside DSL context.

For example, to create a `NavigationView` one can use

```
ankoView({ NavigationView(it) }) {
    lparams(width = wrapContent, height = matchParent, gravity = Gravity.START)
    // more initialization follows
}
```

This way you can instantiate `FloatingActionButton` and `AppBarLayout`, just call their constructors inside `ankoView`'s first argument function. For your convenience, you can make yourself DSL-like functions like in [the manual](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/doc/ADVANCED.md#extending-anko):

```
fun floatingActionButton(init: FloatingActionButton.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ FloatingActionButton(it) }, init)
```

Creating a `Toolbar` is even easier: there is a DSL `toolbar` method in `org.jetbrains.anko.appcompat.v7`.

---

When using Anko DSL, to include another layout, as you did with `content_main`, one can either use Anko [`include`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/README.md#include-tag) function or just write a function which will fill in a `ViewGroup`. You can use this template:

```
fun ViewGroup.myLayout() {
    textView("123")
    // more DSL code here
}
```

Then just call `myLayout()` inside some `ViewGroup` initializer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not ignoring this, I got side tracked overthe weekend.  I did see the section on extending Anko,  and I actually tried to make a toolbar using Anko, but was not able to get io work with the setSupportActionBar() method

Comment: @nPn, make sure that you use `toolbar` method from `org.jetbrains.anko.appcompat.v7` package. IDE messes imports up sometimes, so you might want to write `import org.jetbrains.anko.appcompat.v7.toolbar as tbar` and use `tbar()` function instead. That should work with `setSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: +1 for attempting to help, but sorry,  I am not making progress on this,  I think I really need a good example.  I can get parts of this to work.  I had the most success by putting the UI in a separate class like MyMainUI and then calling MyMainUI().setContentView(this), but ultimately, I can reproduce this simple test case (which is just a blank activity from the android studio template and converted to Kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late answer, but I hope it helps someone. I did the layout this way (of course some styling is still needed):

```
class MainUI(val adapter: MainUIAdapter) : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {

        override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>): View = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            fitsSystemWindows = true

            appBarLayout {
                toolbar {
                    setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE) // so far still needed
                    id = R.id.toolbar
                }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

            }.lparams(width = matchParent)

            relativeLayout {
                id = R.id.container
                recyclerView { // just an example
                    id = R.id.recycler_view
                    adapter = this@MainUI.adapter
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(ctx)
                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent) {
                behavior = ScrollingViewBehavior()
            }
            floatingActionButton {
                onClick { doSomething() }
                imageResource = R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp // the plus sign
            }.lparams {
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
                margin = dip(16)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and used in MainActivity like that:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    MainUI(MainUIAdapter(people)).setContentView(this)

    toolbar = find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no I have not been able to get it to work.  I will probably have to start a fresh project and then take a fresh look at it from the Anko template project.  At this point the project I started this on is out of date.

Comment: When I do this the overflow button is still black. I think it's because I'm not setting the `theme = R.style.AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` property like it does in XML. I can't figure out how to do this in anko.

Comment: sorry for answering so late, but could you perhaps send me or present MWE? Are you setting `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in the manifest?